# Gradle Project sync failed in Android Studio for Ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio

/home/qlooit5/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build.gradle

Error:(5, 0) Invalid revision: 22.0.sample_1
this is what i got as an Error.

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: android {
       compileSdkVersion 22
         buildToolsVersion "22.0.sample_1"
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.qlooit5.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "sample_1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.sample_1.sample_1'
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is your problem:

```
buildToolsVersion "22.0.sample_1"
```

should be:

```
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
```